# Value Object and External libraries

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

We are building our Application using DDD.

We are writing our Domain layer, and in many cases, we need a type for example Money, what is not part of our domain, it is more than just a type for an Entity what is non-exists in the language (PHP).

We don't want to waste time to creating and re-creating libraries what's  already exists.

I'm almost sure in, that the decision for handle Money and which library do we use is shouldn't effect to our Domain, just because it is an implemenatation question.

1. Can we use external libraries under our Domain?
2. Can we define an Interface for ValueObject?
3. Should we put the Money under our Domain? It is not an accounting software, it is just a primitive type what we need to use, but really not important for us. Why should we keep in under Domain?

What is the best way to keep our Domain clear but solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, as long as they don't directly do I/O stuff (filesystem/network/database access) and don't reference infrastructure or I/O related libraries.
2. Yes but why ?
3. Yes, that's precisely what Value Objects are for. An e-commerce domain isn't about mail delivery, yet `CustomerAddress` is a perfectly valid VO there.

Where you might be on to something though is that depending on your domain, Money could be in the Domain layer but in a different [Bounded Context](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) that specifically deals with payment. But it's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question:

1. Yes, you can. But you must understand, that this library becomes a part of your domain. So it must fit your domain specific (for example, if library has 100500 classes and you need just one of them - it's not good to use while library). In common - you can do it.
2. I don't think, it's good idea for value object. If youu need to create an interface for it, it means that it does not fit you in something. Ir looks like and over-architecture for such simple object.
3. Is it really domain object? Maybe it's just simple "well-known" class like `int`, `string`. And you can put it in some `infrastructure` layer. So, every part of your system can use it. We does this in our project. We moved some "all-application" classes and types that "never change" in one `model.infrastructure` library and this reduced mappings and convertions between layer.

But be carefull, this answer as many answers on DDD questions is `primarily opinion-based` because I don't know all your application logic.

Comment: I start with your 3. answer.

I feel Money is not a ValueObject in our Domain. It is not an accounting software, we just want to simply handle the Money in a "good way", and enjoy the additionals what can comes with this lib. For example: `substract`, `add`, `equals`, etc...

Question: If I put this under infrastructure, how can hold my Entity this `Money` type primitive? 

It is unknown at this layer I think, and this is why I was thinking on to create an Interface for this VO with the basic needed functionality later for the infrastructure layer...

Comment: @fureszpeter I see three solutions: include this library in your Domain, create shared library (that can be used by Domain layer) and create Domain interface and implement. I don't know all features of php, so you need to compare wich way is a good compromise between complexity of development and separation of layers and using DDD (DDD is always a compromise, it's really hard to build pure DDD application)